background color changing for frame when lablel is printing
I am trying for label text and button. When doing  the attributes of the frame is changing. i don't understand why.
Here is the code:
 from tkinter import * 
 root=Tk() 
 root.title("Image Processing")

 # set resizing to false
 root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

 # set size of window
 root.geometry('1000x500')

 centerFrame = Frame(root,bg="lightpink",width=1000,height=75)
 centerFrame.pack(expand=TRUE)

 leftFrame = Frame(root,bg="lightblue",width=750,height=750)
 leftFrame.pack(side=LEFT)

 rightFrame = Frame(root,bg="lightgreen",width=1000,height=750)
 rightFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)

 #bt_browse=Button(centerFrame,text="Browse")
 #bt_browse.pack()

 label1 = Label(centerFrame, text="Browse file: " ,width=1000,height=75)
 label1.pack()

 #label3 = Label(leftFrame, text="Column content")
 #label3.pack()

 #label2 = Label(rightFrame, text="Right column")
 #label2.pack()

 # set an infinite loop so window stays in view
 root.mainloop()


Is that what you want?
Change this:
label1 = Label(centerFrame, text="Browse file: " ,width=1000,height=75)

To:
label1 = Label(centerFrame, text="Browse file: ") #<== remove width and height.
Screenshot:

Edit:
Btw, you can reduce the width and height:
label1 = Label(centerFrame, text="Browse file: ", width=10, height=15)

Screenshot:


Background colour of centerframe is missing. I want to get the colour for entire center frame.

Which colour aqua, green or gray?

Grey. When I assign colour it's changing to grey

What is your OS system?
